# How do I pass an array to a constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, constructor

I want to pass an array to a constructor, but only the first value is passed--the rest looks like garbage.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm working on:

```
#include <iostream>

class board
{
    public:
        int state[64];
        board(int arr[])
        {
            *state = *arr;
        }
        void print();
};

void board::print()
{
    for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
            std::cout << state[x + y*8] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int test[64] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,
        6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,
        7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 };

    board b(test);
    b.print();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work and how to properly pass an array? Also, I don't want to copy the array. (And do I really have to indent every line by 4 spaces for code? That's pretty tedious.)

Comment: int (arr&)[64] is the type of your array, and arrays cant be copied.  Easiest to just use std::array

Comment: about the indentation, the IDE usually does this for you.

Comment: About the indentation - you don't need to manually do it for each line separately. Highlight the code and press the button above the edit box that has a pair of braces - `{}` - on it.

Comment: @Default: Yeah, I realized that I just had to go into my IDE, select all, hit tab, and then it's all formatted for this site. Silly me.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Thanks. I'll try that method next time.

Answer (score 10):

In this case it might be best to use a reference to the array:

```
class board
{
    int (&state)[64];

public:
    board(int (&arr)[64]) 
        : state(arr)
    {}

    // initialize use a pointer to an array
    board(int (*p)[64]) 
        : state(*p)
    {}


    void print();
};
```

A couple of advantages - no copying of the array, and the compiler will enforce that the correct size array is passed in.

The drawbacks are that the array you initialize the `board` object with needs to live at least as long as the object and any changes made to the array outside of the object are 'reflected' into the object's state.  but those drawbacks occur if you use a pointer to the original array as well (basically, only copying the array will eliminate those drawbacks).

One additional drawback is that you *can't* create the object using a pointer to an array element (which is what array function parameters 'decay' to if the array size isn't provided in the parameter's declaration). For example, if the array is passed through a function parameter that's really a pointer, and you want that function to be able to create a `board` object referring to that array.

Comment: This works! Thank you. How does this compare with vvnraman's solution?

Also, can you explain what `: state(arr)` does?

Comment: `state(arr)` initializes the reference to the array that's passed as the constructor parameter.

Comment: Can someone explain why the array is bound to `test` and is thus destroyed when it goes out of scope? If two variables are pointing to the same array, why does one have precedence over the other?

Comment: @Svad: the reference is just an alias for the object it's initialized with. The reference has no effect on that object's lifetime.  If you need the `board` object to live longer than the array used to initialize it, then I'd suggest copying the array (which you indicated several times you didn't want to do).  An alternative might be to use `shared_ptr` to manage the array's lifetime; for that you'd need to  create the array in dynamic memory somehow.

Comment: I don't want to copy because I plan to make a very large number of board objects, and copying an array every time would be costly.

So it seems I need to allocate memory. Avram mentioned `new` in another response. I'll also look into `shared_ptr`. Thanks for the explanation and advice.

Answer (score 8):

Attempting to pass an array to a function results in passing a pointer to the first element of the array.

You can't assign arrays, and taking a parameter like `T[]` is the same as `T*`. So

```
*state = *arr;
```

Is dereferencing the pointers to `state` and `arr` and assigning the first element of `arr` to the first element of `state`.

If what you want to do is copy the values from one array to another, you can use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(arr, arr + 64, state); // this assumes that the array size will
                                 // ALWAYS be 64
```

Alternatively, you should look at `std::array<int>`, which behaves exactly like you were assuming arrays behave:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 

class board
{
    public:
        std::array<int, 64> state;

        board(const std::array<int, 64> arr) // or initialiser list : state(arr)
        {
            state = arr; // we can assign std::arrays
        }
        void print();
};

void board::print()
{
    for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
            std::cout << state[x + y*8] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // using this array to initialise the std::array 'test' below
    int arr[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,
        6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,
        7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 };

    std::array<int, 64> test(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    board b(test);
    b.print();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I'm only getting the first value.

I don't want to copy the array, however. Nor do I want to use vectors. Surely there's a way to properly pass an array?

Comment: @SvadHisthana nope, you cannot pass a real array by value in C++. You can pass an array by reference though (and that only helps to figure out the size of it) but that's it.

Comment: I wasn't intending to pass by value. vvnraman's solution is what I was going for. Sorry if I didn't phrase my question better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You have reversed the `std::copy` arguments. They are: `std::copy(first, last, output)`.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer thanks, fixed. Feel free to edit my posts for silly mistakes like that.

Comment: Do note that you can get rid of `arr` in your code.  Since `std::array` is an aggregate you can initialize it like you do a regular array.  This cuts out a step.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

class board
{
    public:
        int * state;    //changed here, you can also use **state
        board(int *arr)               //changed here
        {
          state = arr;
        }
        void print();
};

void board::print()
{
    for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
            std::cout << *(state + x + y*8) << " ";   //changed here
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int test[64] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,
        6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,
        7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 };

    board b(test);
    b.print();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

or you can use it as:

```
class board
{
    public:
        int state[64];
        board(int arr[])
        {
            for(int i=0;i<64;++i)
               state[i] = arr[i];
        }
        void print();
};
```

EDIT 1:
stable solution

```
class board
    {
        public:
            int * state;    //changed here, you can also use **state
            board(int *arr)               //changed here
            {
              state = new int[64];
              for(int i=0;i<64;++i)
                   state[i] = arr[i];
            }
            void print();
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. Though when I tried compiling your first solution, I received an error for line 6: "only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class"

vvnraman's solution seems to be working.

Comment: which is the line? i cant find any assignment of class members outside constructor

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile. You can't initialize a member outside a function using new(). A second issue is that the constructor doesn't copy the contents of the array into the allocated block of memory. It just re-assigns the pointer to point to the array passed into the constructor. This would work in your example code, but in a real program, that memory would become invalid as soon as the array test goes out of scope. The memory allocated and assigned to state would just be leaked.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt see it was outside constructor. yeah you can assign memory inside the constructor and copy array contents to avoid out of scope issues.

Answer (score 0):

`*state = *arr;` is using dereferencing, which returns the value at the address of the pointer.

This is the same as `state[0] = *arr;` because `*arr` is an `int`.

See [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for info on pointers. See the deference section.

To solve this problem you want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) state[i] = arr[i]
```

Comment: Thank you.
However, my program won't compile if I try to change `*state = *arr;` to `state = arr;` I get an error for state saying "expression must be a modifiable lvalue".

Comment: @SvadHisthana See the last line, it will do it for you

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to copy the array. vvnraman's solution seems to be working for me.

Comment: But you might have scope problems in a bigger program. ie if you orginal array goes out of scope

Comment: Beware. That solution will work in this case. However, test is a local variable and a pointer to it won't be valid after the function returns. Of course when main returns the program is done, but you can run into trouble if test wasn't from main. It's a poor design decision to allow this to happen.

Comment: @SvadHisthana Just be careful of the drawbacks if you just copy the pointer, as commented by Seth Carnegie on vvnraman's answer.

Comment: @Avram: Is there any way to keep the array alive independently of `test` without copying it? I guess I don't understand why the array is destroyed when `test` goes out of scope even if another variable is pointing to the array. Can I just make `test` point to something else, or does that affect `state`?

Comment: Short answer, no. The thing with a pointer is that it is little more than an int and its value is a memory address. So just like a variable int i in a function is gone when that function ends, so to test is gone when main ends. And just because some pointer has it's address stored test isn't saved any more than i is. If you want to not have it go, then new/delete are the keywords you need to become familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I'll look into new and delete.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array is the address of the first element in it.

Hence the line `*state = *arr` will set `state[0]` to `arr[0]`.

Since right now you have defined `state` as `int state[64];`, `state` is `const pointer` of type `int` whose address cannot be changed.

You can change it to `int *state;` and then `state = arr` will work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" for state.

Comment: @SvadHisthana I updated the answer as there was a bug in the previous one. I didn't notice that `state` is declared as `int []` which makes it a `const pointer` and hence its address cannot be changed.

Comment: @SvadHisthana remember though that if you do it that way, `state` will point to the same array as `arr` and any changes you make to one will be made to the other. Also if `arr` goes out of scope, `state` will point to a destroyed array

Comment: Good to know. That was the desired behavior.

However, is there any way to preserve `state` in case `arr` does go out of scope?

Comment: To preserve `state`, you would need to allocate memory for it (`state = new int[64];` and then copy the contents of `arr` to `state` (`std::copy(arr, arr + 64, state);` ). Of course if you are going to do this, you would have to implement the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), as now state is a resource.

Comment: So there's no way to preserve `state` without copying the array since the original array declaration is bound to `test`? I just started learning C++ yesterday, so forgive my naivete. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*arr gives the value that is stored at arr[0] . In c++ , the name of the array is a pointer to the first element in the array.

So when you do *state = *arr , you store the value at arr[0] in the variable state.

Now , if you want to pass the array without having to copy each element explicitly , I suggest that you make another array of the same size in the method which you are calling and then pass the name of the array from the caller , in essence :

```
methodWhereArrayisPassed(int *arrayName)
{
    int arrCopy[64];
    arrCopy = arrayName;

// Do more stuff here
}

methodWhichPassesArray()
{
    // do stuff here
    int arr[] = {
       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
       2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
       3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
       4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,
       5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,
       6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,
       7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 };

methodWhereArrayisPassed(arr);

// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: You can't assign arrays like `arrCopy = arrayName`