# C++ Initializing a array in a constructor

Tags: c++

The .cpp :

```
 Person::Person(int _id[9], string name, int age) :_age(age), _name(name){};
```

The .h :

```
private:
int _id[9];
string _name;
int _age;
```

How do I intilaze the 'id' filed in the same method I did with age and name?

Comment: related/duplicate: [How do I pass an array to a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426932/how-do-i-pass-an-array-to-a-constructor)

Comment: use a `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int, 9>`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not have a copy constructor and moreover the parameter `_id` in this constructor

```
 Person::Person(int _id[9], string name, int age) :_age(age), _name(name){};
```

is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array passed in as an argument. That is actually the constructor looks like

```
 Person::Person(int *_id, string name, int age) :_age(age), _name(name){};
```

and the pointer does not keep the information whether it points to a single object or to the first object of an array.

So you should append this parameter with one more parameter that will specify the size of the underlaying array if such is paased as the argument.

For example

```
Person::Person(int *_id, size_t id_num, string name, int age) 
    :_id {}, _age(age), _name(name)
{
    size_t size = id_num < 9 ? id_num : 9;
    std::copy( _id, _id + size, this->_id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person
{
    typedef std::array<int, 9> ids_t;
    Person(ids_t, string name, int age);

private:
    ids_t _id;
    string _name;
    int _age;
};

Person::Person(ids_t id, string name, int age) : _id(id),  _age(age), _name(name){}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what you did in the typedef line?

Comment: @XEvans He created a type alias: now `ids_t` is a type name that is the same type as `std::array<int, 9>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't assign C-style arrays, or even initialize one with another, you could make the task simpler by using a C++-style array (which can be assigned and copy-initialized):

```
array<int, 9> _id;
```

and

```
Person::Person(array<int, 9> id, string name, int age)
: _id(id), _age(age), _name(name) { }
```

Or, if you insist on using a C-style array, you can copy the argument array to the member array with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
Person::Person(int id[9], string name, int age) : _age(age), _name(name)
{
   copy(id, id + 9, _id);
};
```

But note that passing a C-style array is bad because the compiler treats all C-style array arguments as being just pointers to the first element of the array. Thus the type of the `id` parameter is actually `int*` and hence the caller of the `Person` constructor can pass (using the implicit [array-to-pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536)) an array of *any size*, a pointer to just a *single* `int`, or even a `nullptr`, as demonstrated [here](http://cpp.sh/5kou). Trying to copy 9 elements from any of these invalid parameters will result in undefined behavior.